# Existence of module of finite injective dimension

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

At p. 107 of the book *Cohen-Macaulay Rings* by Bruns and Herzog, the authors write

> "any module of finite projective dimension (over a Gorenstein ring $R$) has finite injective dimension as well, simply because $R$ has finite injective dimension by definition."

Could someone please explain why this conclusion is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is Exercise 3.1.25 (the easy part) from the same book. Note that any free module of finite rank has finite injective dimension, and then look at a finite free resolution of the module (that is, decompose it in short exact sequences) starting from the left.

Answer (score 0):

Because a Noetherian ring $R$ has finite injective dimension if and only all R-modules with finite projective dimension also have finite injective dimension. See the proof of this on page $8$, and also the Theorem below there in http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~lee/homolog/Goren.pdf.